# react native - why is this.state is undefined?

Tags: react-native

I am a newbie with React Native. I have this code on my component:

```
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userCategoryType: ''
    }
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    let CategoryType;
    firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot) {
          console.log('An error occured');
      } else {
          CategoryType = snapshot.val().CategoryType;
          alert(CategoryType); // this works
      };
    });
    this.setState({
      userCategoryType: CategoryType,
      loading: false
    });
  }

  render() {        
     alert(this.state.userCategoryType);
     alert(this.state.CategoryType);
  }
```

In render(), when I try accessing this.state.userCategoryType or this.state.CategoryType, I get a message 'undefined'.

What am I doing wrong? Appreciate any help.

Comment: `this.setState({ userCategoryType: CategoryType })` is invalid. there are no variable named `CategoryType`.

Comment: else{
        this.CategoryType = snapshot.val().CategoryType;
 };

this will return you an error, because the this.CategoryType is undefined

Comment: you can try this approach https://pastebin.com/7ijjw8um

Comment: Thanks Ganesh! I tried your code. I am getting an error 'Can't find variable: CategoryType'  in this.setState.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Comment: No, the problem is not yet solved.

Answer (score 0):

I tested it and if you use the component this way it will work find.

```
   constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          userCategoryType: '',
          CategoryType: '',
          loading: false, // change the initial value if you want 
        }
      }   

   componentWillMount() {
        let CategoryType;
        firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {
          if (!snapshot) {
              console.log('An error occured');
          } else {
              CategoryType = snapshot.val().CategoryType;
          };
        });
        this.setState({
          userCategoryType: CategoryType,
          loading: false
        });
      }
```

Note: I didn't check your firebase codes.

Comment: Updated code. I don't see any problem with componentWillMount(). Firebase code also works fine. I added an alert and it does show correct CategoryType from Firebase. However, when I try to access the value in render() as shown in the code, I get a message that it is not defined. Why is that ? Appreciate any help.

Comment: I updated my code, it seems you forget to define some states. try it. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Since I can access the value within Firebase code and not outside, I tweaked the code to:

```
firebase.database().ref('/users/' + userId).on('value', snapshot => {
                            this.setState({
                                    CategoryType: snapshot.val().CategoryType,
                                          })
                                                                     });
```

I can access the value in CategoryType in render() using:

```
alert(this.state.CategoryType);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that calling setState in ComponentWillMount does not cause a rerender.  Try changing ComponentWillMount to ComponentDidMount since this is the recommended lifecycle method for this kind of logic and will cause rerendering on setState.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillmount